# 2 methods for finding a pair of elements from an array with different results

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I have two different functions to work this question out.

**"Find a pair of elements from an array whose sum equals a given number"**

But they both are producing very different results. why are they not producing the same results? 
One is producing 5 pairs the other is 6 pairs, why is this ?

**One is using a double loop.**

```
export function pairElements(arr, arg) {
  var pairArr = arr.slice(); // return a copy of arr
  var result=[];
  for(var i = 0; i < pairArr.length; i++) {
    for(var j = i + 1; j < pairArr.length; j++) {
      if(pairArr[i] + pairArr[j] == arg) {
        let pair = [pairArr[i], pairArr[j]];
        result.push(pair);
     }

   }
 }
 return result;
} 

pairElements([1,4,2,3,0,5,4,3], 7);
result = [ [4, 3], [4, 3], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 3] ];
```

**The second is using the reduce method**

```
 function pairReduce(arr, arg) {
  var pairArr = arr.slice();
  var result=[];
  return pairArr.reduce( function (a,b,index){
      let pair = [];
      let search = arg - b; // get difference of current item so we know what value will sum to arg
      let searchIndex = pairArr.indexOf(search);

      if ( searchIndex != -1 && searchIndex != index){
         pair.push(b, search);
         result.push(pair);
      }
      return result;
  }, 0);
}

pairReduce([1,4,2,3,0,5,4,3], 7));
result = [ [4, 3], [2, 5], [3, 4], [5, 2], [4, 3], [3, 4] ]
```

Comment: logic used is completely different. Not even clear what objective of exercise is

Comment: I gather that! but it still doesn't answer my question. Why is one is producing 5 pairs the other is 6 pairs.

Comment: Use debugger to figure that out. One has multiple loops , the other does something completely different. You are asking us to compare apples and oranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach is quite straight-forward, yet correct by nature: for each element in the array you go through the rest of elements looking for its pair (that'll give the required result if added).

For example, that's what happens on the given input:

```
arr = [1,4,2,3,0,5,4,3]
res = 7
```

First, `1` number (the 0th element) is checked. That means, each subsequent element (starting from `4`, ending with `3`) is added to it, the result is compared to 7. As you see, there's no `6` in that array, so search doesn't give any result.

Then, `4` number is checked, and now things start to be a bit more interesting:

```
4 + 2 = 6 // not added  
4 + 3 = 7 // added!
4 + 0 = 4 // not added
4 + 5 = 9 // not added
4 + 4 = 8 // not added
4 + 3 = 7 // added!
```

So the search gives you two pairs with the same elements - `[4, 3]`. Now let's skip the obvious (`2, 5` pair) and go to `3`:

```
3 + 0 = 3; // -
3 + 5 = 8; // -
3 + 4 = 7; // +
3 + 3 = 6; // -
```

Now you start to see the pattern: this iteration doesn't collect the pair of 'first 4, first 3' - that's already collected. What it gathered, however, is the pair of `first 3, second 4`. Both choices seem to follow the requirements given.

=====

The second approach is somewhat strange. Not only its author for some reason thinks of `indexOf` as a simple operation with constant time complexity (hint: it's not), they also miss the key difference: `indexOf` by its definition gets the first element satisfying its predicate.

So, for example, when `reduce` function goes over first `4` in that array, `indexOf` checks for `3` presence - and finds the first `3`:

```
// reduce on b = 4, index = 1
search = 7 - 4; // 3
searchIndex = arr.indexOf(3); // 3
```

But then exactly the same pair goes into the book when the first `3` is checked (as, again, `indexOf` collects the first `4`).

```
// reduce on b = 3, index = 3
search = 7 - 3; // 4
searchIndex = arr.indexOf(4); // 1
```

But wait, isn't this pair a duplicate? Yes, it is. Ironically, this error is compensated by another one: having the same 'firsts' to be recollected for both second `4` and `3`.

```
// reduce on b = 4, index = 6
search = 7 - 4; // 3
searchIndex = arr.indexOf(3); // 3

// reduce on b = 3, index = 7
search = 7 - 3; // 4
searchIndex = arr.indexOf(4); // 1
```

Yep, two more pairs spotted - and one missed: last elements of array aren't paired.

Can the second approach be fixed? Sure, you can improve it a bit by supplying the second argument into `indexOf`:

```
let searchIndex = pairArr.indexOf(search, index + 1);
```

... but this'll only make it work on arrays with unique elements. Otherwise you'll still need an explicit loop, and that'll essentially make this approach a much more complicated rewrite of the first one.

Comment: Thanks raina77ow for the explanation. Based on your comments is the first example using a double loop the correct one to answer the question ?

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to explain both methods, I appreciate it greatly !